# C++ Linker error with templated virtual method

Tags: c++, templates, linker, polymorphism

I have a templated interface and a templated implementation. I also have a method that takes a specialization of the interface as an argument. I get a linker error:

> "symbol(s) not found for architecture...

Why is that? What is the correct way to achieve this: an interface that works with various types, an implementation that works with various types, and a method that takes as argument the interface specialized on a given type?

The example below is just a minimal example, my actual classes have different functionality.

Thanks

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class IStore{
public:
  virtual T get() = 0;
  virtual void set(T t) = 0;
};

template<class T>
class SimpleStore : public IStore<T>{
public:
  T get() override{    return value;   }
  void set(T t) override{    value = t;  }
private:
  T value;
};

void Print(IStore<double> mydouble){  std::cout<<mydouble.get(); }

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  SimpleStore<double> one;
  one.set(1.0);
  Print(one);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see one major problem with your code: You're taking an abstract class as a value parameter.  This will cause all sorts of bad things.  It may in fact be the source of the problem you're asking about, but I'm not sure on that.

Comment: You're right, replacing `Print(IStore<double> mydouble)` by `Print(IStore<double> & mydouble)` works. I still don't understand why.

Comment: You were forcing the compiler to try to link in pure virtual functions to create a virtual table for a class that can never be instantiated.  It should have resulted in a better error, but whatever.

Comment: I had to read your comment 5 times to understand but I think I got it. Thanks!

Comment: @user1188374 - The mechanism isn't really that important.  It's something the compiler isn't supposed to run into so it's kinda free to do whatever with it.  I'm just guessing that it decided it needed the definitions--logical guess but still just a guess.  The language simply says that you can't do what you were doing or your program is ill-formed.  So just remember that abstract classes (anything with a pure virtual) must never be used as values.  Must always be pointers or references to.